# My code shows no output in the terminal window

Tags: python, binary-search

I wrote a binary search algorithm and tried running it on different editors, i.e pycharm, github, jupiter notebook. And all of them are not showing any output. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
def b_search(num):
   numlist = [12, 23, 34, 54, 67, 81, 99, 102]
   s = 0
   e = len(numlist) - 1
   m = round((s+e)/2)
   n = 1
   found = False
   while (found == False) or ( n != 0):
     if num == numlist[m]
       found = True
     elif num > numlist[m]:
       if m ==s or m==e:
         n=0
       else:
         s = round(m+1)
         m = round((s+e)/2)
     elif num < numlist[m]:
       if m==s or m==e:
         n=0
       else:
         e = round(m-1)
         m = round((s+e)/2)

   if n=0:
     return -1
   else:
     return m

print(b_search(23))
```

I am keen to find any problems in logic or syntax.

Comment: What happens if you add `print("hello")` before and `print("world")` after `print(b_search(23))`?

Comment: Your code can't be run because there're a lot of syntax errors and indentation errors in addition to infinite loop in the binary search logic. You should try running the code from the terminal or other python compilers like Idle or Jupyter which should tell you the lines in the code where there're errors

Comment: `if n=0` should (almost certainly) be `if n==0`

Comment: What steps have you taken to try to find any errors?

Comment: @md2perpe i dry-ran it

Comment: @taxevader i’ll try those!

Comment: @mkrieger1 don’t know no editor would output any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouln't rounded the s and e, you are dealing with **only
   integers**, so thats not necessary.
2. Fixed the identation and logic errors
3. Altough you don't want it to be optimised, when I fixed your code it
   always **return -1.**
4. Added a **check to see if the search range is exhausted** (s becomes
   greater than e). If this happens, it means the target number is not
   in the list, and we set n to 0 to exit the loop.
5. Moved the calculation of m inside the loop to update the middle
   index correctly.
6. Added colons at the end of the if num == numlist[m] and if num >
   numlist[m] lines to correct the syntax.
7. Changed if n=0: to if n == 0: to correct the syntax for comparison.
   (as Sembei Norimaki pointed out)
8. Changed while (found == False) or (n != 0): to while (found ==
   False) and (n != 0): to ensure that the loop continues only if both
   conditions are true.If n = 0 we want to exit the loop, and if we
   find the number we also want do exit.

```
    def b_search(num):
        numlist = [12, 23, 34, 54, 67, 81, 99, 102]
        s = 0
        e = len(numlist) - 1
        n = 1
        found = False
        while (found == False) and (n != 0):
            m = round((s + e) / 2)
    
            if num == numlist[m]:
                found = True
            elif num > numlist[m]:
                s = m + 1  # Update s directly without rounding
            else:  # num < numlist[m] (if it isn't >, certainly is =<)
                e = m - 1  # Update e directly without rounding
    
            if s > e:  # Check if the search range is exhausted
                n = 0
    
        if n == 0:
            return -1
        else:
            return m
    
    print(b_search(23)) #outputs 1
    print(b_search(99)) #outputs 6
    print(b_search(100)) #outputs -1
    print(b_search(12)) #outputs 0
    print(b_search(102)) #outputs 7
    print(b_search(54)) #outputs 3
    print(b_search(81)) #outputs 5
```

Comment: Ohh okay i understood the infinite loop part but what does the last if statement in while loop do? Comparing s>e?

Comment: The if s > e: statement is used to check if the search range has become invalid, which can happen when s becomes greater than e (search range is empty, and the target number is not in the list) then setting n to 0 allows the loop to exit

Comment: If, at any point, s becomes greater than e, it indicates that the search range is empty (there are no elements left to search), and therefore, the target number cannot be found in the list

checking if s > e: check is crucial to avoid an infinite loop and ensures that the algorithm does not continue searching when it's clear that the number is not present.